# LDAP Search String for Two OUs

Tags: ldap, scanning

I am looking to include two separate OUs in an LDAP search string.  I've searched for answers and found some but none seem to work once I include the second OU.  Specifically, this is to narrow down a scan to email list on a Canon Copier.  The following string works on a single OU:

OU=People (Staff),DC=DOMAIN1,DC=DOMAIN2,DC=com

I'd like to add a second OU so all emails included in the second OU are also available in the scan to email address search.  The second one is OU=People (Vendors)

I can remove the OU completely but the search takes too long without the extra filter.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

The [Extensible Match Search Filter](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch#section-ExtensibleMatch-SearchWithinTwoContainers) supports this functionality assuming that your LDAP server implementations supports that functionality. (**Microsoft Active Directory does NOT support this**)

```
(&(|(ou:dn:=People (Staff))(ou:dn:=OU=People (Vendors)))(objectclass=inetorgperson))
```